# Paho MqttClient with QoS=2 - Higher used HeapSpace

Tags: java, heap-memory, mqtt, paho

I am using the eclipse Paho Mqttv5 client and the mosquitto broker.
When I subscribe with QoS=2(ExactlyOnce) e.g MqttProperties occupy more and more space of the heap.
Even if I stop the publishing application the MqttProperties(among other classes from the paho framework) are not beeing released by the GarbageCollector(Even If I force the GC to run).

The applications used Heap space is rushing up and peaks at abt 80-90%  of the Max Heapspace after a few minutes.

If I switch to QoS=1(AtLeastOnce) The used heap space is nearly constant.

I could ask myself if QoS=2 is really necessary - but I would like to understand what is going on here.

**EDIT**:

I gave both Applications a max heap size of 1G, it seems they both peak at about 210M

[image: Heap Application #1]

Application1: receives 1 Message every 100ms

[image: Heap Application #2]

Application2: receives 7 Messages every ~150ms(at once!)

A messages is about 20bytes

So the only difference I see is that Application #2 is reaching the peak faster because of the higher workload.

But as far as I observe right now - even after I stop the publishing the memory is not beeing released. Is there a buffer for the messages to be Acknowledged in QoS=2 which fills up and is reused after a certain amount is reached?

Comment: What are your message sizes and rates, does it level off at 80-90% and run fine (just with more frequent GC)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hardillb I hope my edit makes it clearer

Comment: Java garbage collection only happens when there is a failure to allocate a new object, so if the load is stopped then nothing is allocating objects so there will be no GC

Comment: yeah but even if I do ` jcmd <pid> GC.run` there is nothing released